# Yii framework - save model with decimal property

Tags: php, yii

I have column in the database with type of column decimal(10,2).

When I try it save model with number (for example 45.28), so the value stored in the database is 45.00

Why are not saved number after the decimal point?

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you created the model using Gii, make sure that in `rules()` the property `integerOnly` is **false**.

```
array(......'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>false);
```

Another possible solutions:

```
array('your-attribute', 'type', 'type'=>'float'),
array('your-attribute', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[0-9]{1,10}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/'),
```

Comment: Are you using other localization?, I'm from venezuela and we use commas for decimals, but the database was configured to receive dots for decimals. Do you have any beforeSave method?

Comment: We use dot for decimal. I do not have beforeSave method.

Comment: When I save it with queryBuilder, so the number is correct in the database.

Comment: I've updated the answer with more possible solutions.

Comment: I try it your updated unswer, but it still does not save.
I solved it with queryBuilder.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Doesn't yii , when using gii, represent decimal types as strings? I would expect it to save all values if that were the case.